# Quotes in JQuery / JavaScript when using PHP print function

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, quotes

I'm trying to debug someone's code and have hit a bit of a rookie error.

Now while this works on Xserve (or at least it kindly ignores it), when running on a linux server it refuses to co-operate and knocks out a function lower down.

I'm pretty sure what I need to do here is address the quotes: the scope of the quotes seems to be wrong - the first double quote links to the third and the second to the fourth. Any ideas very very welcome!

```
<?php foreach ($years as $id => $title) : ?>
$("#<?php print $id ?>_both").click(function() {
$(".<?php print $id ?>.g, .<?php print $id ?>.b")
.attr("checked", $("#<?php print $id ?>_both").attr("checked"));
});
<?php endforeach;
```

Comment: Is the problem that the PHP isn't generating the JS you expect? If so, show the PHP and the generated JS and explain how the latter differs from what you expect.

Comment: Is the problem that the JS doesn't work and you think it should? If so, don't bother showing us PHP. Just show us generated JS.

Comment: I thoroughly dislike debugging other people's code! This issue is that I am getting a debug error that a semi-colon is expected, which appears to have knocked out a datepicker function below this section of code

Comment: Is that a PHP error or a JavaScript error?

Comment: @Holly - Can you post the generated JS, as suggested by @Quentin? It's difficult to see where the problem may lie, as we don't know what the PHP is going to produce.

Comment: What's that code supposed to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quotes look okay (awful, but okay).  Are you sure you aren't missing an end php (last line):

```
<?php foreach ($years as $id => $title) : ?>
$("#<?php print $id ?>_both").click(function() {
$(".<?php print $id ?>.g, .<?php print $id ?>.b")
.attr("checked", $("#<?php print $id ?>_both").attr("checked"));
});
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: I thoroughly dislike debugging other people's code! This issue is that I am getting a debug error that a semi-colon is expected, which appears to have knocked out a datepicker function below this section of code

Comment: I hear ya about other people's code.  Does the end php ?> fix the problem?

Comment: sadly no - debug is returning:  SCRIPT1015: Unterminated string constant

Comment: Since the OP doesn't clarify ,I think that the PHP end tag isn't needed. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/819297/php-tag-closing-when-is-needed

Comment: You're a genius! Thanks. One additional quote (tbh I was clutching at straws by that point) and it works! Celebratory coffee....